# Получить данные с 2 таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

Имеется 2 таблицы "Товары" и "Заказы" некоторые поля имеют одинаковые названия.
Можно ли получить данные из 2 таблиц в 1 запросе чтобы все поля были (даже те которые одинаковые)?

Мой вариант получает все поля, но те которые одинаковые он получает со 2 таблицы (затирая первую).

```
$items = self::leftJoin('orders', 'items.id', '=', 'orders.item_id')->get();
```

Items

```
id
name
city_id
area_id
party
weight
data
status
created_at
updated_at
```

Orders

```
id
user_id
city_id
area_id
item_id
from
data
status
payment_system
payment_message
message
complete
delete
created_at
updated_at
```

Суть такова, что нужно получать все записи с таблицы Items, кроме тех, что имеют в таблице `Orders` тот же `item_id` и `status = 'payment_wait'` или `status = 'payment_ok'`

P.S. Цель - получать список товаров кроме тех, которые забронированы.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2`. А вообще дайте пример таблиц (схемы) и у вас есть какой-то `Join`...

Comment: ->select('*', orders.status as orders_status") все поля которые дублируются надо подписать или явно выбрать

Comment: @binliz а как подписывать или выбирать? мне по сути с второй таблицы нужно только item_id и status

Comment: вот ваш запрос перед ->get() вставить ->select('*', orders.status as orders_status")

Comment: а почему не делать это через связи(отношения)???

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев Таблицы Orders[item_id] связана с Items[id], но как это использовать в запросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Item extends  Model{

    // получаем все заказы на данный товар
    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

}

class Order extends Model {

    // получаем товар по заказу
    public function item(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }

}
```

Таким способом устанавливается связь между таблицами в Laravel.

Получить товары с их заказам:

```
Item::with("orders")->get();
```

Чтобы указать статус товаров которые не должны войти в список:

```
Item::with("orders")->where("status", "!=", "Тут значение статуса")->get();
```

Чтобы получить все товары которые не имеют ни одного заказа в таблице "orders"

```
Item::doesntHave("orders")->get();
```